# Converting a reflection method to a compiled lambda

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I'm new to lambda. So excuse me if my question is simple.

I have a method that uses reflection to set a property on some types:

```
public void WriteId(object obj, int id) {
    var type = obj.GetType();
    var prop = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                   .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
                   .Where(p => p.Name == "Id")
                   .Where(p.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
    if(prop != null)
        prop.SetValue(obj, id, null);
}
```

Can you show me please how can I create a lambda that do same job? Actually I want to create a lambda for each type, compile it, and cache it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780232/assign-property-with-an-expressiontree

Comment: @Dennis Thanks to link. I saw it, but it was more complicated to me to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would install [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember) from NuGet, and then use:

```
var wrapped = ObjectAccessor.Create(obj);
obj["Id"] = id;
```

which does pretty much what you say, except it happens to use `ILGenerator` via `TypeBuilder` (rather than `Expression`) - but all the caching etc is there.

A second cheaky approach is to get `dynamic` to do it all for you:

```
((dynamic)obj).Id = id;
```

But if you want to use `Expression` for other reasons:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;   

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Foo { Id = 2 };
        WriteId(obj, 6);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Id); // 6
    }

    private static class SneakyCache<T>
    {
        public static readonly Action<T, int> SetId;
        static SneakyCache()
        {
            var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
            var id = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "id");
            SetId = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, int>>(
                  Expression.Assign(Expression.Property(obj, "Id"), id),
                  obj, id).Compile();
        }
    }
    public static void WriteId<T>(T obj, int id) where T : class
    {
        SneakyCache<T>.SetId(obj, id);
    }
}
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @MarkGravell Thanks to pretty quick answer. I don't want to use prepared code. I want to learn. Can you show me lambda (or ilgenerator) code to do this please?

Comment: @king.net added lambda approach; I can add ILGenerator if you want. The use of generics in the above is a handy way of doing the cache very conveniently, but if you **only** have `object`, we can work around it

Comment: @MarkGravell I see right now you are the owner of FastMember. Thank you. well done good job. Where can I find FastMember's source to study and learn please? Can I?

Comment: @king.net you can *probably* just use the one-liner, though - `dynamic` is quite handy for a few things: `((dynamic)obj).Id = id;`

Comment: @MarkGravell but what happen if the obj has not a Id property?

Comment: @king.net in any of the cases shown, it will throw an exception, basically saying that there was no "Id" property.